# Apache flink - move files to a different folder after reading

Tags: apache-flink

I am reading csv files from a directory and doing some processing.
Right now flink just picks any new file that comes in that directory and processes it. This is working fine for me.

I am stuck in 2 issues:

1. I want to log the file names that flink has finished processing.
2. I want to move processed files to a different folder as soon as flink completes the processing.

My code snippet is :

```
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path filePath = new org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path(feedFileFolderPath);

RowCsvInputFormat format = new RowCsvInputFormat(filePath, FetchTypeInformation.getTypeInformation());

DataStream<Row> inputStream = env.readFile(format, feedFileFolderPath, FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY,
                parseInt(folderLookupTime));
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This topic has come up a couple of times on the flink mailing list -- see the discussion [here](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/ContinuousFileMonitoringFunction-deleting-file-after-processing-td9604.html#a9606) and [here](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/%3C1520561551416-0.post@n4.nabble.com%3E) -- but the short summary is that there's not yet an easy way to do this from within Flink.

What seems to be commonly done is to use a cron job to periodically move older files out of the directory being monitored, with the assumption that they've been processed. If you want to be more careful than that, then you'll have to implement your own mechanism for tracking the progress of the job doing the processing. The email threads referred to above include some ideas of how to do that.

Comment: i have a same requirement.
is there any finding on this?

Comment: David Anderson: Its been a long time that this use case was raised by a flink user(in 2018).Even today i have the same use case.Just wanted to check if flink has updated this feature in any of its version
?

Comment: @Sam The only significant change is the addition of the FileSource, which will ultimately replace readFile. But the issue being asked about here remains.